# marker google maps swift infowindow

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, google-maps, marker

hello  I am working with google maps and have the following questions

I want to display information of a marker in a fixed label and every time you touch will change the label.

I have the following code which I understand I can make the event a marker

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker!) -> Bool {
    self.nameService.text = "example"
    return true
}
```

but this function does not work , ask the above function is for that?

I also tested this function to change the infowindow but neither works

```
 func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {

    let index:Int! = Int(marker.accessibilityLabel!)

    let customInfoWindow = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindow", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! CustomInfoWindow
    customInfoWindow.label.text = "example"
    self.nameService.text = "example"
    return customInfoWindow
}
```

I 'm making that mistake ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

try with the following code

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker!) -> Bool {
    self.nameService.text = "example"
    return false
}
```